# Excel VBA Macro: Match Column A and B, copy duplicates to Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I am having a little trouble figuring out a macro to help me with some of my data. I have come across a couple macro's that almost do what I need, but I don't know enough about the language yet to figure it out. This is what I am working with.

Column A - List of software.

Column B - Version of software.

Column C - Computer names it is installed on.

What I am looking for. I need a macro to search for duplicates that match both Column A and B. If it has a duplicate, I need it to copy the duplicates and original rows to Sheet2.

Now Sheet2 should only have duplicate items on it. Would it be possible to search for duplicates again (Column A&B), when it gets a match, JoinRange of the Column C's together. Then delete the duplcates.

Ex:
Column A (Software)

Adobe Reader X

Adobe Reader X

Adobe Reader X

Adobe Reader XI

Adobe Reader XI

Column B (Version)

10.1.6

10.1.6

10.1.7

11.0.03

11.0.03

Column C (Computers)

Computer1,Computer2

Computer3,Computer4

Computer5,Computer6

Computer7,Computer8

Computer9,Computer10

---

Finished product would be:

Column A

Adobe Reader X

Adobe Reader X

Adobe Reader XI

Column B

10.1.6

10.1.7

11.0.03

Column C

Computer1,Computer2,Computer3,Computer4

Computer5,Computer6

Computer7,Computer8,Computer9,Computer10

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I could sure use some guidance.

V/r,
Brett

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple.  Add a sheet called "Duplicates", then select the sheet you want to check for duplicates, then make sure the sheet is sorted first by col A next by Col B, then run this macro:

```
    Sub GetDuplicates()
    On Error GoTo errGetDuplicates
    d = 1
    x = 1
    Do Until Cells(x, 1) = "" 'Looks at each row until it reaches the end
        If Cells(x, 1) = Cells(x + 1, 1) Then 'Checks Col 1 for duplicates
            If Cells(x, 2) = Cells(x + 1, 2) Then 'Checks Col 2 for duplicates
                Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 1) = Cells(x, 1)
                Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 2) = Cells(x, 2)
                Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 3) = Cells(x, 3)
                d = d + 1
                x = x + 1
                Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 1) = Cells(x, 1)
                Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 2) = Cells(x, 2)
                Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 3) = Cells(x, 3)
                d = d + 1
            End If
        End If
doneWithError:
        x = x + 1
    Loop

    Exit Sub

errGetDuplicates:
    If Err = 1004 Then
        array1 = Split(Cells(x, 1), " ")
        array2 = Split(Cells(x + 1, 1), " ")

        For a = 0 To UBound(array1)
            If Not array1(a) = array2(a) Then GoTo unmatched
        Next a

        array3 = Split(Cells(x, 2), " ")
        array4 = Split(Cells(x + 1, 2), " ")

        For a = 0 To UBound(array1)
            If Not array3(a) = array4(a) Then GoTo unmatched
        Next a

        Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 1) = Join(array1, " ")
        Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 2) = Join(array3, " ")
        Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 3) = Cells(x, 3)
        d = d + 1
        x = x + 1
        Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 1) = Join(array2, " ")
        Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 2) = Join(array4, " ")
        Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 3) = Cells(x, 3)
        d = d + 1

        GoTo doneWithError

    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Matthew, thanks for the quick reply. The macro works great for the most part... I'm having an error whenever it gets to a cell with a lot of information in it. It says "Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error"     It wont copy it over to the Duplicates sheet. Any suggestion?

Comment: I doubt that is the issue. Is the Duplicates sheet named Duplicates? Do you keep the sheet you want to run it on selected until the macro is finished? Is the sheet you are running it on sorted correctly? If none of those are the problem, post the sheet and I'll help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I just checked and they are sorted correctly. It runs correctly for a couple rows but gets hung up. I checked the cell it got hung up on and copied it to Word and there is 830 words (4 pages) of text.

Comment: I started to delete some of the information in the cell to see if that was the issue. I got down to 505 words (3 pages) of information and it was able to run the Macro past it, but got hung up at the next larger cell.

Comment: Wow.  That is a lot.  I've never heard of that happening before.  If you hit the break key and debug, which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: Sheets("Duplicates").Cells(d, 3) = Cells(x, 3)    The first one

Comment: Just to try it, add the sheet name to the second reference too for all the lines. If your running this on a sheet called data, change Cells(x,3) to Sheets("data").Cells(x,3).

Comment: I just added that to the macro. Same result, it works for a few of them until it hits the cell with a lot of information. Is there a way to divide a cells information in half to the next cell over?

Comment: Try the edited macro above.  Make sure you take the whole thing, as I added code in several places.